# Display content from HTML tag in different Wordpress pages?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, parsing

Im working on a Wordpress portfolio site and there is a line of text

```
<?php get_template_part( 'post-meta-page' ); ?>
```

that pulls information from that file and displays it on the page. Right now it displays only the title of the blog/page. I want it to display a unique line of text for each page while keeping the original title. I looked into it a little bit and this could be referred to as parsing?

Example: from external file.

```
<html>
  <p class="homepage">Text for homepage</p>
  <p class="interior">Text for interior page</p>
  <p class="contact">Text for content page</p>
</html>
```

In other words, I want to call a specific class on one page and another class in another page. Any snippet of Javascript or PHP that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `post-meta-page` page and check where you are and add the appropirate text.

For example:

```
if(is_home()){
     <p class="homepage">Text for homepage</p>
}
```

Comment: For multiple pages/posts/templates text to be included consider using PHP switch cases with the switch variable as the determined current page/post

Comment: Oh and remember that is_home() checks if the current page us the blog index page. If you are checking if the homepage is being used (fron wfat gas been set in reading options > honepage) try this = is_front_page()

Comment: In the the 'post-meta-page' there is this line of code, '<h1 class="entry-title post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>' It displays the title of the page but I want this to display a custom class like stated above. Where would I put that code?

Comment: @DavidBerning why not underneath it?

Comment: and you can use `is_page('name-of-page')` to check for specific pages if you need specific chunks for those

Comment: I'll have to mess around with it. First attempt with Wordpress.

Comment: @DavidBerning try deleting all the text from the page. See the difference. Then add in your own code. then do the `is_home()` and those sort of checks and you should get the hang of it